# Restoring a "Canceled" event with Google Calendar API?

Tags: gdata-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to change the status of an event back from "canceled" to "confirmed" using Google Calendar API (I'm using .NET but an answer in any language would help) but I get GDataRequestException error:

"You can't modify a cancelled event"

If I've used the API to delete an event in a repeating series, for example, is it possible to change the status of the resulting recurrence exception (there's no EXDATE, just a new "canceled" event that is only visible when the feed is requested with start and end date) to "confirmed" (or even delete the resulting exception completely) in order to restore the repeating series to the original state?

event.Delete() and event.Update() don't even see the event any longer once it's been .canceled. event.Update() gives the above error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's impossible to change any parameter for an event once it's set to cancelled, including the status "cancelled". I had to work around the issue by creating new recurrence exceptions with "Original Event" specified.

Answer (score 1):

Found the following way: first obtain the occurrence id (which happens to be in the `<masterId>_<date>` format) by calling `/instances` endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/<masterEventId>/instances?showDeleted=true
```

Then call `PATCH` and change the status of the cancelled occurrence:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/<occurrenceId>

{
    "status": "confirmed"
}
```

Comment: That's great news - the API now allows us to patch any deleted events :) Hopefully next they'll allow the same thing for entire calendars! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Note that the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#status) does list some caveats: "Such cancelled events will eventually disappear, so do not rely on them being available indefinitely. Deleted events are only guaranteed to have the id field populated."

Answer (score 0):

We can also use **[get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get)** with parameter `eventId`, where we need to enter the `id` of the event. We get all the information about this event. I think that, in a pinch, we can create a new event based on this data.